# Есть ли задержка между двумя запросами к бд в php?

Tags: php, mysql

На сервере есть два скрипта: comments.php и db_api.php.

db_api.php - это как бы низкоуровневый скрипт для работы с бд.

```
class db_api{
...
  public function create($req){
        $stmt = $db->prepare($req);
        $stmt->execute();
  }
  public function read($req){
        $stmt = $db->prepare($req);
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $data;
  }
}
```

comments.php - отлавливает конкретные запросы от клиента к бд, обрабатывает данные и обращается к db_api.php.

```
function create_and_read_res(){
   //обрабатываем запрос
   ...

   $db->create($req); //создаем запись
   $data = $db->read($req); //получаем все записи
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Это неполный код. Вопрос, может ли возникнуть ситуация, когда php-сервер выполняет команду $db->read($req) до того, как бд сделала запись? Т.е. до того, как выполнилась команда $db->create($req)?

Ну, например, сервер нагружен. Юзер пишет комментарий, страничка автоматически обновляется, а его комментария там нет.

Как ведет себя php? Он переходит к выполнению следующей команды только тогда, когда mysql выполнит первую? Или же нужно самостоятельно отлавливать ответ от mysql и прописывать коллбеки?

Comment: Там всё синхронно. В примере вашем `$db->read` всегда после `$db->create`. Но да, если юзер обновит страницу, то есть шанс, что комментария нового ещё нет.

Comment: собсно, значит mysql и php проводят все эти рукопожатия (получение ответов о выполнении команд) на низком уровне сами. Благодарю.

А то я с ноды на пхп перешел.. ну ты понял.